# Working with API's in a Angular project

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am newbie on API's so this question might be silly.

I am trying to structure login / register on the Angular project and I have API for this. But I checked a lot of login / register structure. They uses one enpoint. Its called '/login' for example. But I have three endpoints:

```
/authenticate,
/authorize,
/token
```

authenticate params: username, password, client_id, redirect_uri, scope

authorize params: client_id, client_secret, redirect_uri

/token params: code

I got it login structure by this service:

```
var loginUser = function (User, callback) {
  var fullApiPath = serviceROOT + 'authentication';
  $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: fullApiPath,
    data: User
  }).
  success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    callback(data, status, headers, config);
    console.log('ok');
    $location.url('/profile');
  }).
  error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log('Fatal request on = ' + fullApiPath);
    callback(data, status, headers, config);
  });
};
```

Yes, it works but I do not know how to proceed after that or its a good solution.

How can I proceed? Any demo or example for like this structure?
If you can help I would be very happy. Thanks.

Comment: I'd think this would be better served on [codereview.se], but I'm not sure.

Comment: @ShotgunNinja it's not exactly clear what's being asked here. Code works, which indeed sounds like a Code Review would work, **but** OP seems to be asking where to go from there... which is *too broad* for SO and off-topic for CR, since it seems to be basically asking for new code / functionality, which CR doesn't do. I voted to close as *unclear what you're asking*.